# How can I hide skipped jobs from GitHub Actions UI?

Tags: github-actions

A job will be marked as `skipped` if the `if` condition on the job is `false`. But the job is still shown in GitHub Actions workflow UI. Is there a way to hide it if it is skipped?
I am working on a monorepo which includes many projects, I don't want to see all those skipped projects.

Comment: You unfortunately can't hide the jobs from a workflow run, even if they are not executed. If it's not an issue, a workaround could be to use a different workflow for each operation, according maybe to the path updated in the monorepo folders?